# How to show that a smaller video file streams fasters than a bigger video file?

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, video-encoding, mpeg-dash

I have a simple video player app in Android that plays two videos given a URL. One a smaller mp4 file and the other one a bigger sized file. Basically, I want to show that the smaller mp4 buffers and plays faster simply because of it's smaller size and that more contents need to be downloaded. But I have problems showing this concept and what I did doesn't really work like that. I initialize the second player after the first one, and get the time to buffer 100% of the URL video and show it below each player. Apparently it doesn't show what I'm intending to prove.

What am I doing wrong here? What are ways to make it prove the concept?

[image]

Here is my simple code:

```
package com.example.videoplayer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //https://dl5.webmfiles.org/video-h264.mkv
    //https://s3.amazonaws.com/x265.org/video/BigBuckBunny_2000hevc.mp4
    private static final String VIDEO_SAMPLE =
            "https://dl5.webmfiles.org/video-h264.mkv";
    private static final String VIDEO_SAMPLE2 =
            "https://dl5.webmfiles.org/video-h265.mkv";
    private VideoView vw1, vw2;
    private TextView mBufferingTextView,mBufferingTextView2;
    // Current playback position (in milliseconds).
    private int mCurrentPosition = 0;
    // Tag for the instance state bundle.
    private static final String PLAYBACK_TIME = "play_time";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        vw1 = findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        vw2 = findViewById(R.id.videoView2);
        mBufferingTextView = findViewById(R.id.buffering_textview);
        mBufferingTextView2 = findViewById(R.id.buffering_textview2);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(PLAYBACK_TIME);
        }

        // Set up the media controller widget and attach it to the video view.
//        MediaController controller = new MediaController(vw1.getContext());
//        controller.setMediaPlayer(vw1);
//        vw1.setMediaController(controller);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Load the media each time onStart() is called.
        initializePlayer();
        initializePlayer2();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // Media playback takes a lot of resources, so everything should be
        // stopped and released at this time.
//        releasePlayer();
    }

    private void initializePlayer() {
        // Show the "Buffering..." message while the video loads.
        mBufferingTextView.setVisibility(VideoView.VISIBLE);
        // Buffer and decode the video sample.
        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(VIDEO_SAMPLE);
        vw1.setVideoURI(videoUri);

        // Listener for onPrepared() event (runs after the media is prepared).
        vw1.setOnPreparedListener(
                new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        // Hide buffering message.
//                        mBufferingTextView.setVisibility(VideoView.INVISIBLE);

                        // Restore saved position, if available.
//                        if (mCurrentPosition > 0) {
//                            vw1.seekTo(mCurrentPosition);
//                        } else {
//                            // Skipping to 1 shows the first frame of the video.
//                            vw1.seekTo(1);
//                        }

                        // Start playing!
                        vw1.start();


                        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
                            boolean buffered = false;
                            @Override
                            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i) {

                                if(i==100 && !buffered) {
                                    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                    mBufferingTextView.setText((t1 - t0) + ", " + i + " ");
                                    buffered = true;
                                }
                            }
                    });
                    }
        });

    // Listener for onCompletion() event (runs after media has finished
    // playing).
        vw1.setOnCompletionListener(
                new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()

    {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion (MediaPlayer mediaPlayer){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Completed",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Return the video position to the start.
        vw1.seekTo(0);
    }
    });
}

    private void initializePlayer2() {
        // Show the "Buffering..." message while the video loads.
        mBufferingTextView2.setVisibility(VideoView.VISIBLE);
        // Buffer and decode the video sample.
        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(VIDEO_SAMPLE2);
        vw2.setVideoURI(videoUri);

        // Listener for onPrepared() event (runs after the media is prepared).
        vw2.setOnPreparedListener(
                new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        // Hide buffering message.
//                        mBufferingTextView.setVisibility(VideoView.INVISIBLE);

                        // Restore saved position, if available.
//                        if (mCurrentPosition > 0) {
//                            vw2.seekTo(mCurrentPosition);
//                        } else {
//                            // Skipping to 1 shows the first frame of the video.
//                            vw2.seekTo(1);
//                        }

                        // Start playing!
                        vw2.start();


                        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
                            boolean buffered = false;
                            @Override
                            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i) {

                                if(i==100 && !buffered) {
                                    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                    mBufferingTextView2.setText((t1 - t0) + ", " + i + " ");
                                    buffered = true;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

        // Listener for onCompletion() event (runs after media has finished
        // playing).
        vw2.setOnCompletionListener(
                new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()

                {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion (MediaPlayer mediaPlayer){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "Completed",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // Return the video position to the start.
                        vw2.seekTo(0);
                    }
                });
    }


    // Release all media-related resources. In a more complicated app this
    // might involve unregistering listeners or releasing audio focus.
    private void releasePlayer() {
        vw1.stopPlayback();
    }
}
```

And the layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <!-- adding VideoView to the layout -->
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/buffering_textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Buffering..."
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/buffering_textview2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Buffering..."
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Playing speed does not depend on size of o file. Frames per second is the same.

Comment: Yes but I mean downloading and buffering from network are different. Simply the player needs to download more contents to start playing.

Comment: Well then you could better reformulate and edit your post as there is nothing about sooner starting to play. And what does encoding have to do with it? And what can we see on that image? Pretty confusing all.

Comment: @TinaJ If I get the question correct, You can buffer fixed video duration, let's say 5 sec of each video and show a toast it took x seconds to download first 5 seconds. Or you can create the app to make playback of other type horrible. like loading in the middle of playing...

Comment: @blackapps i edited the question. But streaming means network streaming of video

Comment: @hmr umm can you elaborate more? The videos are identical tho...same duration anyways.

Comment: In a nutshell,

Video 1 : 5MB, 60 seconds
Video 2 : 13MB, 60 seconds

You want to show video 1 will load faster than video 2.

Comment: Yes. So how to show this concept? Any ideas? I would like to somehow compare them 1-1.

Comment: Why not trying to throttle the network speed, in order to appreciate the buffer speed better, also try to show a buffer progress bar, like YouTube does

Comment: @nestorperez good idea. How can I throttle the bandwidth?

Answer (score 1):

I checked the 2 videos in your code: video 1 has a bitrate of 4 MBPS and video 2 is at 2 MBPS. (I tested both with https://ffprobe.a.video to get the bitrates).

If the tester is on Wi-Fi, and has 10 MBPS of network throughput, both videos will download and playback with no issue.

IDK how to throttle inside an Android app. If this app is just for demonstration purposes, set up a laptop with Charles Proxy to throttle the network, and connect the android device through the Charles Proxy.

Other ways to demonstrate:  get a "really big" video. Like 20 (or 40 or 50)  MBPS.  Then create a 5 (or 10) MBPS version.  Then you might see more buffering on a 'traditional' network connection without the throttling.

Note:  One of your videos is h264, the other is h265.  If you want to do an apples:apples, I'd recommend having both videos with exactly the same format - just to reduce the number of variables in the experiment.

Comment: Tnx. Right, so bc one video is having larger bitrate, the "time" it takes to buffer the first video should be larger, regardless of if player can play them or not. And yes- my point is showing h265 bc of its smaller size takes less time to buffer and loads faster.